# Why does my C++ function, only when it's placed after main(), not work?

Tags: c++, function, program-entry-point

I recently picked up C++ and decided to try out making a function. However, I've run into a problem with my function `func()` where, even if declared beforehand, it only works if it's placed before the `main()` function.

If I place it after the `main()` function, the system tells me there is "no matching function for call to `func`".

Note: the function`func2` on the other hand works even if placed before or after the `main()` function.

So here's the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

void func2();

int func();

int main()
{
  int y=2;

  std :: cout << "Hello World\n" << func(y) << "\n";
  func2();
  return 0;
}

int func(int x)
{
 x *= 2;
 return x;
}

void func2()
{
 std :: cout << "Hello there";
}
```

Comment: As a general rule you should always declare your functions before using them. You should also declare them *exactly* as they are defined.

Comment: In C, `func()`, and `func(void)` once were meaning different thing, in C++ it's same thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In C language, the declaration `int func();` means *a function with an unspecified number of arguments of any type, returning a* `int`.

In C++ language, the same declaration `int func();` means *a function **without any** arguments, returning a* `int`.

And therefore, in C++, the definition of `func` with an argument of type `int` is an *overload*. For the compiler, it is a *different* function, which in the original code is not declared before use, so an error is emitted.

But in C, it would be perfectly legal.

Comment: Minor detail: definition of a function with a different set of arguments is not a *contradiction* but an *overload*.

Comment: @IgorG You are right. I will edit my answer to correct that.

Comment: @GiorgosTsolakidis even in C that feature is marked as outdated. Some calling conventions on modern platforms literally cannot support it, even the new version "fast" call on Windows I think.

Answer (score 5):

```
int func();
```

and

```
int func(int x)
```

See the difference? The first one should be

```
int func(int x);
```

You told the compiler that `func` was a function with no arguments, then when you tried to call it with one argument the compiler said 'no matching function'.

Comment: The key here is that in C++ you can have two functions with the same name, but different arguments, unlike C where you cannot and you'd have a conflicting definition.

Comment: @tadman at least older versions of C allowed to declare without arguments, just name and "unknown count of arguments", then proper argument were responsibility of caller. to declare function without any arguments, one had to say `int func(void)`

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I'd prefer not to remember K&R C.